# Tag governance?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does anyone (the community?) decide when to police tags? For example, let's say someone asks a Python question and adds the tags `python` and `c` even though the question as nothing to do with C, but Python is written in C.

Other examples. The question is about [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) is tagged with both `jquery` and `javascript`. The question is about [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL), but it is tagged with both `sql` and `php`. The question is about Three.js, but it is tagged with both `three.js` and `webgl`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the community polices this. Anyone can [suggest an edit to a question (or answer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), and part of that edit includes the ability to add/remove tags as appropriate. Those suggested edits are reviewed by other community members; when they receive 3 votes of approval, they take effect. If not, they are rejected.

Then there are users who have [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) after gaining at least 2,000 reputation. These users can edit any part of questions (and answers), including retagging them.

And yes, the process does work. Questions are *frequently* retagged by more experienced members of the community. The examples you gave should be cleaned up rather quickly. If you see something that's wrong, don't hesitate to try and fix it!

Comment: Ask any iOS developer about H2CO3 and the `xcode` tag, for example...